# Who is my parent component / parent name in Svelte 3

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, svelte-3

I have a component which is used by different kind of components (parents). This component's behaviour slightly depends on who is his parent (the kind of parent).

Ofcourse I can pass the parent's name as a prop or bind or ...

**My question:** Is it possible for the nested component to find out by itself who is the parent? during onMount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and this is by design. If the parent and child components are designed to work together, they can communicate via props, events, or using the [Context API](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/context-api).

Comment: OK. I think maybe I can hack something using a "this binding (bind:this=..)" and then looking in the dom for the parent. But we skip the hack and pass a prop with a component kind id.